# Errors caused by gunicorn procfile in Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a small django app on Heoroku using the documentation provided. But my app does not run and when I look at the logs on Heroku it looks like the problem is with the procfile. Here are the contents of the procfile. Is this the correct syntax?

```
web: gunicorn hashem3.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT
```

And here is what the Heroku logs show:

```
2012-07-21T03:02:58+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Add shared-database:5mb add-on by 
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by xxx
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Add PYTHONUNBUFFERED, PYTHONPATH, PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, LANG, PYTHONHOME, LIBRARY_PATH, PYTHONHASHSEED config by xxx
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by xxx
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by xxx
2012-07-21T03:04:28+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9805b83 by xxx
2012-07-21T03:04:29+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2012-07-21T03:04:30+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn hashem3.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8157`
2012-07-21T03:04:31+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2012-07-21T03:04:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-07-21T03:04:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-07-21T03:04:32+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2012-07-21T03:04:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn hashem3.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:54714`
2012-07-21T03:04:35+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: gunicorn: command not found
2012-07-21T03:04:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2012-07-21T03:04:36+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-07-21T03:05:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET floating-atoll-1969.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
2012-07-21T03:05:18+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET floating-atoll-1969.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 by
```

tes=

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You forgot to add guinicorn as a dependency in your requirements.txt file.

Comment: Yup, that was it! So I added gunicorn to my req file and again deployed. But I get a different error this time. I'm using django-storages to connect to S3. When I looked at the logs again, its saying "ImportError: No module named storages". I uninstalled and reinstalled storages, verified its in my req file and then deployed again. Still get the same importError.

Answer (score 0):

Check here for the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python/). In particular, the **Using A Different WSGI Server** section.